# How to define a javascript function from Chromium Console

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, chromium

I'm trying to define a Javascript function or a simple variable in Chromium Browser debugger console. After definition, when I cannot reach this function. What shall be the problem for it?

Here are the variable and function definition that I write on the chromium console:

```
var myvar;

var f = function(){
   console.log("Hello world");
};

function f2(){
   console.log("Hello world");
};
```

By the way, I can reach the functions that I created at Mozilla Firefox Browser.

What is the problem with Chromium Browser?

Comment: `var function = f(){` is a syntax error. What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Don't use `function` as a variable name, you'll get an unexpected token error

Comment: Sorry for the mistake while defining function f. I corrected it. After I define a function from Chromium console, I expect to call those functions or variables. However, I can't. What shall be the reason for it?

Answer (score 5):

function is reserved word in javascript.

Try this

```
var f = function() {
   console.log("Hello world");
};
```

instead of

```
var function = f(){
   console.log("Hello world");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
function fun(a,b)
{
   console.log(a,b);
}

fun(5,6); // calling
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write

```
document.myFunc = function(){alert("Hello");}
```

Call it with

```
document.myFunc()
```

But I'm not an expert